# How can I change a String in JAVA with a Button click?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

My App contains a Keyboard Layout with Stickers. All Stickers are inside a "pack" inside an `recyclerView`.

If I change the name of the `PACK_lib` manually into the name of the packs like "allstickers" and build then it works and shows only the stickers of "allstickers".

Can I handle this with a button ? 
I created two buttons , `b1` and `b2`.

If the user clicks `b1` it should change the `Pack_lib` String into "allstickers".
If the user clicks `b2` it should change the `Pack_lib` String into "teststickers".

The buttons needs to change on click the name from "allstickers" into "teststickers" inside the code the java file.

Please help.

I tried to give the button IDs and using the code of `setText`. But it didnt work. Also tried to `setVisibility` but also doesnt work.

**Stickers.java**

```
private void setDefaultStickerPack() {
        checkVersion(true);
        InputStream in = null;
        String packList[]=new String[0];
        final String PACK_LIB = "allstickers";
        final String PACK_APP="pack_app";
        final String PACK_ICON="pack_on.png";
        String curAssets="";
```

**main_board_layout.xml**

```
  <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="allstickers"
            />

  <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="teststickers"
            />
```

The user should click on the button and the pack should switch from "allstickers" to "teststickers"

Comment: You can use the `android:onclick` attribute for simplicity for now. Make sure Stickers.java is an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the string simply change your string in OnClick Listener of the button.

```
String sticker = "";

final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

           sticker = "allstickers";
        }
      });
final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

           sticker = "teststickers";
        }
      });
```

Comment: Should I add these lines inside the "Sticker.java" where the string is or a seperate java class? Because there are many errors of "Cannot resolve method findById and "View"" when I just add it under the string.

Comment: You should paste these lines of code where you are inflating your main_board_layout.xml

Comment: is Sticker.java a class or activity?

Comment: Sticker.java is a class.

Starts with -> 

public class Stickers {
    private static final String TAG = "Stickers";
    private static final String PACK_DATA_LIST = "PACK_DATA_LIST";
    private static final String SAVE_VERSION = "SAVE_VERSION";
    public StickerpacksResponse stickerpacksResponse;
    public final List<PackData> packDataList;
    public List<PackData> packDataListDefault = new ArrayList<PackData>();

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private long lastDownload = 0;
    private Context lContext;

Comment: Inflating the main_layout is in another Java called "KeyboardService".

Comment: Inflating the main_layout is in another Java called "KeyboardService". 
- > public class KeyboardService extends InputMethodService 
But the main activity is another Java. Can you contact me via mail or skype? @Lekr0

Comment: show your activity and all the related class in proper format